# Where did sublinear tf-idf originate?

Tags: references, text-mining, information-retrieval, weights

I have often come across this weighting scheme for tf-idf ([term frequency - inverse document frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Term_frequency.E2.80.93Inverse_document_frequency)) in text mining. I am wondering where it came from (for citations). I've searched very rigorously, but can't seem to find anything. Specifically, this is the weighting scheme:

$$
{\rm tfidf}(t,d,D)=(1+\log({f_{t,d})})\cdot \log\!\bigg(1+\frac{N}{n_t}\bigg)  \\
N=|D|
$$

where $t$ is the query term, $d$ is the document, $D$ is set of documents, $n_t$ is the document frequency of $t$, $f_{t,d}$ is how many times $t$ appears in $d$

Comment: Please describe what all the notation in the equation means.

Comment: What's your question? Is it just a reference request?

Comment: @C11H17N2O2SNa Yes. Where did this come from?

Comment: It is related to Zipf's law, check it out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law)

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a reference to justify my use of sublinear tf. I couldn't find where it originated from, but if you just need a reference you can use *An introduction to information retrieval*, 2009, C.D. Manning et al. Section 6.4 is on variant tf-idf functions that includes sublinear tf scaling.